# Custom Expandable List with different content

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandable

I want to create a activity where contains first fix content like buttons and images and then a expandable list. But in the expandable list as well I want to appear different content like google maps map, images, calendar, text... like I put in the image below.

[image]

I tried to find examples about how to make that but I only found activities who has only the expandable list (with out the buttons and images above) and the expandable list only have text inside and not different content as I need. Someone knows where to find a good example? or how can I do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try our following tutorial:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/

you can use getView() of the adapter to provide your own view.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial... it helps me to at least to make the view like I wanted. Now the problem is that I can´t introduce the map as child. It gave me the following error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown> I have the <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> added in the manifest and actually google maps works in other activity that I have. If you know why it can be please let me know!

Comment: please post your code where you are adding map view and the logcat stack trace in the original question with code formatting..

Comment: I already open a thread with this problem are there you can find the code. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048207/error-trying-to-add-a-map-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line if you need something more please let me know. And thanks for your help!

Comment: If this answer solve your original question then please accept the answer so that other people would not spend their time on this question..

Comment: It doesn´t solve my original question because what I want is to put different thing like map, images, calendar and so on and in this moment I can create a expandable list where I can put only text.